# Suppose each of A,B, and C is a nonempty set. Prove that if (AxB) is a subset of (BxC), then A is a subset of C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose each of A,B, and C is a nonempty set. Prove that if (AxB) is a   subset of (BxC), then A is a subset of C.

Comment: no what I have is correct

Comment: Can you prove if AxB is a subset of CxD then A is a subset of C and B is a subset of D?

Comment: What I have is the correct question that I was assigned.

Comment: @fleablood’s question is pertinent to the one that you were assigned; if you can prove the result in that question, you can use it to prove the one in your problem.

Comment: Well then yes i can prove that fairly easily, but I'm not sure about the A is a subset of C part.

Comment: @Cantwait428: Apply **fleablood**’s result to your hypothesis that $A\times B\subseteq B\times C$. You get two set inclusions. Then combine them suitably.

Comment: So since A is a subset of B, and B is a subset of C, then A is a subset of C?

Comment: @Cantwait428: That’s right.

Comment: Ok I was thinking that but I couldn't think of how to say it, but now I get it, thanks

Comment: @Cantwait428: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in A$.  Select any $b \in B$.  Then $(a,b) \in A \times B$.  So $(a,b) \in B \times C$.  So $a \in B$.  So $A \subset B$.

Let $b \in B$.  Select any $a \in A$.  Then $(a,b) \in A \times B$.  So $(a,b) \in B \times C$.  So $b \in C$.  So $B \subset C$.

So $A \subset C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y$ are nonempty then so is $X\times Y$ and the projection functions $\pi_1\colon X\times Y\to X$, $\pi_2\colon X\times Y\to Y$ are surjections.

Thus, if $A,B,C$ are nonempty and $A\times B \subseteq A\times C $, then $B = \pi_2(A\times B)\subseteq \pi_2(A\times C) = C$.